# migration fails on heroku due to activeadmin mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

I am deploying an app to heroku and the app is on rails 3.2 and I have active admin gem installed.

When I run rake db:migrate it fails due to the following error

```
    ==  DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrating =========================================
-- create_table(:admin_users)
   -> 0.0823s

Sent mail to admin@example.com (3228ms)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Wondering what I need to do to fix this. It seems that the Devise gem or ActiveAdmin needs to send mail during the migration process and because it can't if fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the Sendgrid addon:

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter
```

If you are deploying to the Aspen or Bamboo [stacks](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack), it should work right away. If you are using the Cedar stack, you need to add an additional initializer:

```
#config/initializers/mail.rb

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Taken from: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Comment: I'm using cedar so I suppose I will just need to look up the documentation for setting that up? Thanks for the tip. Will this post after I give it a try.

Comment: adding send grid fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing me a little:

```
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Do you have your mail setup?  Are you using SendGrid or similar?  Remember that Heroku don't provide email services directly.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Comment: yeah that was confusing to me as well ... still need to trouble shoot it a bit and see if SendGrid needs to be set up